Container script error in Apt "Get: command not found" and "Reading: command not found"
I'm putting together a basic chaos engineering script for a personal project, and I'm encountering a weird error in a Kubernetes cronjob container, but I'm having a hard time isolating it.
Kubernetes configmap containing the Script:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: chaos-script
data:
  chaos-script.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    BASE_URL="https://${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}:${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT}/api/v1/namespaces/foo"

    echo "$0: searching/installing curl..."
    stat /usr/bin/curl 2>/dev/null || $(apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl)
    echo "$0: searching/installing jq..."
    stat /usr/bin/jq 2>/dev/null || $(apt-get install -y jq)
    echo "$0: done searching/installing packages"
    ...

Output:
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: searching/installing curl...
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: line 5: Get:1: command not found
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: searching/installing jq...
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: line 7: Reading: command not found
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: done searching/installing packages
...

"Get:1: command not found" and "Reading: command not found" seem to be coming from Apt, if I do set -x, I get:
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: searching/installing curl...
++ apt-get update
++ apt-get install -y curl
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
+ Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease '[256' 'kB]' Get:2 http://security...
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: line 5: Get:1: command not found

and
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: searching/installing jq...
++ apt-get install -y jq
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
+ Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... The following additional packages will be installed...
/scripts/chaos-script.sh: line 7: Reading: command not found

Everything seems to be functioning ok, so, it's more of a curiosity, but does anybody know what to do to eliminate these errors?
